# Convert Javascript into jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new in jquery and I having trouble in converting my JavaScript into jquery ajax I tried but I did not get it properly if anyone can help me I shall be very thankful to him/her.

**how my code works:**

When i click on a edit button a popup is displayed showing record of a person and we can edit it in popup and then save it.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

**This is my JavaScript Ajax code:**

```
function update(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","updateattendence.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Edit">
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
I have tried jquery get method but I can don't know how to call my JavaScript function. and It is showing nothing.

Comment: Could you share with us the code where you tried to use jQuery.get method?

Comment: Please share what you tried using jquery ajax

Comment: I did share it cause I don't think that would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) would be:

```
function update(str)
{
  if (str=="") {
    $("#txtHint").html("");
    return;
  }

  $.get('updateattendence.php', { q : str }, function(response){
    $('#dialog')
      .html(response)
      .dialog();
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you sir this code worked fine but what you suggest me whether i use get method of jquery ajax or and ajax method of jquery ajax.

Comment: `$.get()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax` with limited options so if don't need all the options that the latter provides then the former is fine. It also depends on personal preference, some people just use `$.ajax` exclusively and don't bother with the shortcuts `$.get()`, `$.post()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
function update(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  $("#txtHint").html("");
  return;
  } 
 $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/updateattendence.php?q="+str,
        success : function(responseText) {
        $("#dialog").html(responseText);
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        }
       });
}
```